# Creating an array from 1 keys array and 1 values array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays that look like this:

```
    ["Test", "Test2", "Test3"]
    ["ID1", "ID2", "ID3"]
```

I need to create an array from the above arrays that looks like this:

```
    ["Test": "ID1", "Test2": "ID2", "Test3": "ID3"]
```

I'm currently doing this but this is not correct:

```
    var new_arr = [];
    var something = 'Test';
    var something2 = 'ID1';
    
    var n = ''+something+':'+something2+'';
    
    new_arr.push(n);
```

This code produces the following which is not right:

```
    ["Test:ID1","Test2:ID2"]
```

Could someone please advise on this?

Comment: Your desired output is not valid JavaScript. Are you sure you want an *array*?

Comment: You need to make an array of objects, the syntax you provided is not valid. Something like this is what you are looking for I think `[{"Test": "ID1"}, {"Test2": "ID2"}, {"Test3": "ID3"}]`

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet, yes thats it. thats what I need to do.

Comment: check @trincot answer, then ;)

Answer (score 4):

What you want seems to be a better fit for a plain object, not an array.

For that you can use `map` and `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
let keys = ["Test", "Test2", "Test3"];
let values = ["ID1", "ID2", "ID3"];

let obj = Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key, i) => [key, values[i]]));

console.log(obj);
```

Or if you need separate objects, each with just one key/value pair, then use a computed property name in an object literal:

```js
let keys = ["Test", "Test2", "Test3"];
let values = ["ID1", "ID2", "ID3"];

let arr = keys.map((key, i) => ({ [key]: values[i] }));

console.log(arr);
```